# Short Form of Bash Script IF ELSE Not Working

Tags: bash

The script is basically polling directory `/images` for jpg files and moving them to new directory `/gallery/2022-06-14/` while also renaming (removing initial characters). I was planning to add another action along where if existing time is between 000000 and 050000, bash script should invoke python script by taking `renamed file path` as argument.

Can you tell if its not possible to use short form of `if` in this manner? Why its erroring out?

```
find '/images' -maxdepth 1 -name '*jpg' -exec sh -c '''echo mv {} /gallery/$(date --date="today" '+%F')/$(basename {} | sed "s/^.\{,19\}//") && [[ ! ( `date +"%H%M%S"` < 000000 || `date +"%H%M%S"` > 050000 ) ]] && python3 python-script.py "/gallery/$(date --date="today" '+%F')/$(basename {} | sed "s/^.\{,19\}//")"''' \;
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: And why the `python` tag when the question is about `bash`? Removed.

Comment: You're using `sh` but `[[` which is specific to `bash`. Change the command `sh` to `bash` might help with this.

Comment: BTW, triple-quotes (`'''`) aren't a thing in shell syntax. The shell will parse that as a zero-length quoted string (`''`) followed by a regular single-quote (`'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if its not possible to use short form of if in this manner?

It is possible.

> Why its erroring out?

*That specific error* is most probably because you used sh instead of bash. `[[` is super special for Bash with special syntax rules and it specially handles `(`.

Anyway, the code is unreadable, and uses an `find` extension and is not protected against spaces in filenames and has issues. Do not use backticks, prefer `$(...)`. Consider a different approach, where you do not have to super double quote everything:

```
work() {
  echo "$somevar"
  somevar2="$2"
  # normal code here, you could use variables.
  echo mv "$1" "/gallery/$(date --date="today" '+%F')/$(basename "$1" | sed "s/^.\{,19\}//")"
  if [[ ! ( $(date +"%H%M%S") < 000000 || $(date +"%H%M%S") > 050000 ) ]]; then
     python3 python-script.py "/gallery/$(date --date="today" '+%F')/$(basename "$1" | sed "s/^.\{,19\}//")"
  fi
}
somevar=1
export somevar
export -f work
somevar2=2
find .... -exec bash -c 'work "$@"' _ {} "$somevar2" \;
```

Comment: I am also trying to pass count of total image files in work() or in other words, i dont want to run python code if total array length in find is more than 5

Comment: ? Then pass it. I do not understand. You can use an argument, or export the variable.